# How to show and hide a user input triggered by a reactive from another module?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, modularization

I've been showing/hiding UI items using Shiny `conditionalPanel()` and shinyjs `show`, `hide`, and `toggle` functions. However, in this multi-module example I'm stuck. I'm trying to show/hide the `selectInput()` in the second module (`mod2`), triggered by the action button "Calculate" in the first module (`mod1`). Until the "Calculate" action button is clicked, I would like the "Select Series" `selectInput()` to be hidden. As shown in the below illustration.

Below is a skeleton version of my 2-module code. What I am having difficulty with is how to hide `selectInput()` in the `mod2_ui` when the unhide is to be triggered by the reactive `common$calc_click` which comes from the `mod1_server`. Essentially, I'm trying to have actions from the `mod1_ui` govern actions in other modules too. Any suggestions? I'm trying to avoid `renderUI()` because of the problems it presents (speed, invocation flashing, etc.) but perhaps that is unavoidable. Maybe some else has better ideas?

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)

seriesTrm <- data.frame('Series_1' = c(1,2,3),row.names = c("A","B","C"))

mod1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(
    calcBttn = actionButton(ns("calculate"), "Calculate"), 
    allocTable = textOutput(ns("alloc_tbl")),
    info_text = uiOutput(ns("click_warn_1"))
  )
}

mod1_server <- function(id, common, input) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    calc_click <- reactiveVal(FALSE)  
    allocData <- reactiveVal()
    
    observeEvent(input$calculate, {
      calc_click(TRUE)
      common$mod1_data <- allocData  
    }) 
    
    output$click_warn_1 <- renderText(if(!calc_click()){"Click Calculate to render mod1 table"}) 
    observe({common$calc_click <- calc_click()})
    output$alloc_tbl <- renderText({if(calc_click()){"Mod1 table appears here"}})
  }) 
}

mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(
    seriesSelect = selectInput(ns("seriesSelect"), "Select Series", choices = NULL),
    mod2Output = textOutput(ns("series_tbl")),
    info_text = uiOutput(ns("click_warn_2"))
  )
}

mod2_server <- function(id, common, input) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    reactive_choices <- reactive({colnames(common$seriesTbl_1())})
    observe({updateSelectInput(session, "seriesSelect", choices = reactive_choices())})
    calc_click <- reactive(common$calc_click)
    output$click_warn_2 <- renderText(if(!calc_click()){"Click Calculate to render mod2 table"})
    output$series_tbl <- renderText({if(calc_click()){"Mod2 table appears here"}})
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
 tableOutput('hottable_1'),br(),
 mod1_ui("mod1")$calcBttn,br(),br(),
 mod1_ui("mod1")$info_text,
 mod1_ui("mod1")$allocTable, br(),
 mod2_ui("mod2")$info_text,br(),
 mod2_ui("mod2")$seriesSelect, br(),
 mod2_ui("mod2")$mod2Output 
) 

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  seriesTbl_1 <- reactiveVal(seriesTrm) 
  observeEvent(input$hottable_1, {seriesTbl_1(hot_to_r(input$hottable_1))})
  
  output$hottable_1 <- renderTable({seriesTbl_1()})
  
  common <- reactiveValues(seriesTbl_1 = reactive(seriesTbl_1()))
  mod1_data <- mod1_server("mod1", common, input)
  mod2_server("mod2", common, input)
}) 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Build a dynamic UI that reacts to user input](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/dynamic-ui/) one option would be to use a helper `output` to store the value of `calc_click` which can then be used in the `condition` of a `conditionalPanel` like so:

```
mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(
    seriesSelect =
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "output.show_series",
        selectInput(
          ns("seriesSelect"), "Select Series",
          choices = NULL
        ),
        ns = ns
      ),
    mod2Output = textOutput(ns("series_tbl")),
    info_text = uiOutput(ns("click_warn_2"))
  )
}

mod2_server <- function(id, common, input) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    reactive_choices <- reactive({
      colnames(common$seriesTbl_1())
    })
    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "seriesSelect",
        choices = reactive_choices()
      )
    })
    calc_click <- reactive(common$calc_click)
    output$click_warn_2 <- renderText(if (!calc_click()) {
      "Click Calculate to render mod2 table"
    })
    output$series_tbl <- renderText({
      if (calc_click()) {
        "Mod2 table appears here"
      }
    })
    output$show_series <- reactive({ calc_click() })
    outputOptions(output, "show_series", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  })
}
```

[image]

[image]